# python requests login and get url after login

Tags: python, forms, authentication, python-requests

So I've been trying for some time to login this website http://dom-site-0979-grgwrggtkj.dynamic-m.com:171/index.html and I can provide the username and password since these are not secret (privacy doesn't matter). So the code I've written so far is:

```
import requests
def remote_login():
    url = 'http://dom-site-0979-grgwrggtkj.dynamic-m.com:171/index.html'
    payload = {'txtUserId': 'zach26276',
                'txtPwd': 'password'}

    p = requests.post(url, data=payload)

    print(p.text)
    print(p.url)
```

I've used Fiddler to try and see the output but all I see is SSL encrypted stuff even though it should be using only form data. I've already tried the hidden inputs to no avail. I think the problem may be in the fact that this uses YUI javascript to parse the form data and to authenticate, but the form method is still POST so requests should work right?

What I get with requests is error 500 with:

```
<HTML>
<BODY>
<HEAD><TITLE>SYSTEM ERROR</TITLE></HEAD>
<H1>INTERNAL ERROR</H1>
The operation cannot be completed.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: did you try to see the post request with the chrome network tool?

Comment: I tried to analyze it but when I click the login button it tells me that username/password are not correct and doesn't even do the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the request you will see that the post url is 'http://dom-site-0979-grgwrggtkj.dynamic-m.com:171/login.json' and also the body is like :

> {'uName': 'zach26276',
>              'pwd': 'password'}

I think you will also need to set the header content type to json.
Check requests.Session(), if you want to do a bot to navigate it's awesome.

Also the website return a bad username/password but the answer HTTP tells that a user is already in, not that good to debug.

Comment: I've already used session but mostly used it to do a POST, I guess session is better for header setting. thanks, sorry for my crap debugging skills

Comment: I changed it do requests in json and I effectively get valid session keys after login, but the part of getting the url is not working. Do i need to see redirects or something?

Comment: Try to do a get(indexUrl) after the login.

Comment: well, but I don't know the url after login. If I get the login url after post will that work? like get(http://dom-site-0979-grgwrggtkj.dynamic-m.com:171/)

Comment: The website is unreachable so I can't help you.
The easiest way is to do the navigation manually with the google chrome inspector and check the "preserve log" in the network panel. So you can check the request and still get the 302 (I think) which is a redirection.